# Как сделать чтобы при наведении на элемент плавно добавлялся задний фон у другого блока?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Суть такая, при наведении на один блок должен плавно меняться задний фон у другого, чтобы это выглядело красиво, 2 дня уже сижу не могу сделать.. И хотелось бы с событием которое будет следить за мышью (mouseover и mouseleave). Заранее спасибо!

```css
.reg__container-right {
  width: 400px;
  /* background: url(../img/shadow__right.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; */
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: left;
}

.reg__container-left {
  width: 400px;
  /* background: url(../img/shadow__left.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; */
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: right;
}

.cart__reg-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart__reg-container">
  <div class="reg__container-left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, molestiae asperiores possimus omnis tempore eius nam nesciunt molestias odit esse quis assumenda libero corporis totam, illum cum laudantium, iusto facere!
      <p>
  </div>
  <div class="reg__container-right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, molestiae asperiores possimus omnis tempore eius nam nesciunt molestias odit esse quis assumenda libero corporis totam, illum cum laudantium, iusto facere!
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Также хочу обратить Ваше внимание что один background будет располагаться в правой части блока, а у другого блока он будет в левой части соответственно. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что в качестве бекграунда у вас будут изображения, а не просто цвет.

```js
var containers = $('.reg__container-left, .reg__container-right').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        containers.not(this).addClass('show_bg');
        $(this).removeClass('show_bg');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        containers.removeClass('show_bg');
    }
});
```

```css
.reg__container-left,
.reg__container-right {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}

.reg__container-right::after,
.reg__container-left::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-size: contain;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.reg__container-right::after {
    background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sRjjG6i1f48/UKdHmcOMwtI/AAAAAAAADPM/Ga7HeGO58nY/s1600/texture_of_ice-background_for_websites.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}

.reg__container-left::after {
    background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1d/b6/f8/1db6f831d030b86af7564436a6cb37d8--old-paper-background-dark-places.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

.show_bg::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.cart__reg-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart__reg-container">
    <div class="reg__container-left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, molestiae asperiores possimus omnis tempore eius nam nesciunt molestias odit esse quis assumenda libero corporis totam, illum cum laudantium, iusto facere!
            <p>
    </div>
    <div class="reg__container-right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, molestiae asperiores possimus omnis tempore eius nam nesciunt molestias odit esse quis assumenda libero corporis totam, illum cum laudantium, iusto facere!
            <p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`transition`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) + [`mouseenter`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)/[`mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) :

```js
$('.reg__container-right').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('.reg__container-left').css('background', 'red');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('.reg__container-left').css('background', '');
});

$('.reg__container-left').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('.reg__container-right').css('background', 'red');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('.reg__container-right').css('background', '');
});
```

```css
.reg__container-right {
  width: 400px;
  /* background: url(../img/shadow__right.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; */
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: left;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.reg__container-left {
  width: 400px;
  /* background: url(../img/shadow__left.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; */
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: right;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.cart__reg-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart__reg-container">
  <div class="reg__container-left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, molestiae asperiores possimus omnis tempore eius nam nesciunt molestias odit esse quis assumenda libero corporis totam, illum cum laudantium, iusto facere!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="reg__container-right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, molestiae asperiores possimus omnis tempore eius nam nesciunt molestias odit esse quis assumenda libero corporis totam, illum cum laudantium, iusto facere!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```